How can I call a regexp callback function in hook_ckeditor5_plugin_info_alter()?
I am trying to capitalize the first character of a typed sentence following what described in Automatic text transformation (autocorrect).
// Finally, you can define `to` as a callback.
// This (naive) rule will auto-capitalize the first word after a period, question mark, or an exclamation mark.
{
  from: /([.?!] )([a-z])$/,
  to: matches => [ null, matches[ 1 ].toUpperCase() ]
}

In Drupal, using hook_ckeditor5_plugin_info_alter() and trying to add the plugin definitions like below, it recognizes the regular expression, but the first character is not capitalized because the callback does not work.
How can I use the callback in this code?
$plugin = $plugin_definitions['ckeditor_text_transformation_textTransformation']->toArray();
$plugin['ckeditor5']['config']['typing']['transformations'] = [
  'remove' => ['arrowLeft', 'arrowRight'],
  'extra' => [
    [
      'from' => 'CKE', 
      'to' => 'CKEditor',
    ],
    [
     'from' => ['regexp' => ['pattern' => '/([.?!] )([a-z])$/']],
     'to' => ['callback' => ['matches'=> 'NULL , matches[1].toUpperCase()']],
   ],
 ],
];
    $plugin_definitions['ckeditor_text_transformation_textTransformation'] = new CKEditor5PluginDefinition($plugin);

